Captions in Title Case (with mfirstuc & Koma-script)
I would like to change automatically my float captions to be in Title Case. The captions may contain \label{...} as shown below. I think I get pretty close with mfirstuc, as I get the capitalization to work with a label within main body of the text but not within the captions.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
%\MFUexcl{\label} % no effect?
%\MFUblocker{\label}  % no effect?
%\gMFUnocap{\label}  % no effect?

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{casing}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=casing}

\begin{document} 
    


\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{this is my figure heading for first figure} % does not capitalize
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
        \hline
        Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
        Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows.} % does not capitalize
\end{table}

\xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows} %works
%\ecapitalisefmtwords{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows} %throws an error

\end{document}
    

The solution does not need to use mfirstuc but should be compatible with Koma-Script.This question is related to a similar post but keeping these seperate in order not to complicate that post more.


with a current latex you could use \ExplSyntaxOn\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{casing}{\text_titlecase_all:n{#1}}\ExplSyntaxOff

Exchanging the row starting with \DeclareCaptionTextFormat with your snippet throws and error. Do you mind adding your comment as an answer with MWE?

As already done in my answer to your previous question, I recommend to move the \label behind the \caption argument. In case of using \ecapitalisefmtwords you have to move the \label outside the argument, because as the documentation of the package tells, the command first expands the argument. \label uses \protected@write to write to a file. So it is not expandable. Note also, that the command is not transparent for \xcapitalisefmtwords. So you should move the \label outside of its argument too.
So for single line captions you could do something like:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\scr@@makesinglelinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{this is my figure heading for first figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
        \hline
        Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
        Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{a simple table with three columns and three rows.}\label{tab:my_table}
\end{table}

Why you should not use \verb|\label| inside the argument:

Try: \label{x:my_label}\xcapitalisefmtwords{a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.%works

Try: \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{x_my_label2}a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.% does not work

Try: \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{x_my_label3} a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.% also incorrect

Try: \label{e:my_label}\ecapitalisefmtwords{a simple table with three columns
  and three rows}.% works too

\end{document}


For captions spanning several lines, you would need to redefine or patch \scr@makemultilinecaption, e.g., add
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\makeatother

to the document preamble.
But, if your really like to have the \label inside the \caption argument, this also works. But you should remove the space after \label{…} and add it to the blockers.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\MFUblocker{\label}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\scr@@makesinglelinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\xpatchcmd{\scr@makemultilinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\label{fig:my_label}this is my figure heading for first figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
        \hline
        Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
        Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\label{tab:my_table}a simple table with three columns and three rows and a somehow
      long captions with more than a single line.}
\end{table}

Why you should not use \verb|\label| inside the argument:

Try: \label{x:my_label}\xcapitalisefmtwords{a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.%works

Try: \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{x_my_label2}a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.% does not work

Try: \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{x_my_label3} a simple table with three
  columns and three rows}.% also incorrect

Try: \label{e:my_label}\ecapitalisefmtwords{a simple table with three columns
  and three rows}.% works too

\end{document}


But, because of the space issue, you should be careful. Otherwise you will have an additional space after the Figure 1: or Table 1::
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\MFUblocker{\label}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\scr@@makesinglelinecaption}{#3}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#3}}{}{\PAtchFailure}
\makeatletter

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{this is my figure heading for first figure}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% Just to compare the formatting
    \caption{\label{fig:my_label} this is my figure heading for first figure}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% Just to compare the formatting
    \caption{\label{fig:my_label2}this is my figure heading for first figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Note: This is IMHO not a problem of \label and surely not of \caption or KOMA-Script, but a problem of using \label inside \xcapitalisefmtwords.
Yes, I've removed package caption from the preamble, because you've told in the question, that your first priority is KOMA-Script compatibility. When using package caption an answer would be completely independent from using KOMA-Script. So if using caption is important for you, you should ask a question using a standard class and do not use tag koma-script.

This is neat. Please see my follow-up question for using the caption package here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731752/captions-in-title-case-with-mfirstuc-and-caption-packages
