Captions in Title Case (with mfirstuc and caption packages)
I would like to change automatically my float captions to be in Title Case. The captions may contain \label{...} as shown below. I think I get pretty close with mfirstuc, as I get the capitalization to work with a label within main body of the text but not within the captions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
%\MFUexcl{\label} % no effect?
%\MFUblocker{\label}  % no effect?
%\gMFUnocap{\label}  % no effect?

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{casing}{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=casing}

\begin{document} 
    
    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{this is my figure heading for first figure} % does not capitalize
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \hline
            Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
            Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows.} % does not capitalize
    \end{table}
    
    \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows} %works
    %\ecapitalisefmtwords{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows} %throws an error
    
\end{document}
    

The solution does not need to use mfirstuc and should use the caption package as I use it for other caption customizations as well.This question is related to a similar posts (here & here) but keeping these seperate in order not to complicate them.
P.S. I am using R packages table1 and kable for producing tables. They both place the label inside caption, which is the way some people recommend doing it.


Once again: You should move the \label behind \caption{…}. Case changing is somehow complicated and not expandable macros like \label are therefore often a problem. BTW: The linked page also does not recommend to put it inside.

I get the point of moving the label. The software I am using (see edited post), places them inside and I would rather change the way I use latex than try to change all the software I am using or their behavior.

I already explained why \ecapitalisefmtwords{\label{…}…} cannot work and why \xcapitalisefmtwords{\label{…}…} is not really a good idea → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731750/277964.
The real argument passed to the command defined by \DeclareCaptionTextFormat is not only the caption text, but something like \ignorespaces … \caption@makeanchor {…}. So \xcapitalizefmtwords can only fail with the real caption text is inside another group. We can adapt the definition of format empty and use:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{casing}{%
  \caption@caps#1\caption@makeanchor{}\@nil
}
\long\def\caption@caps#1\caption@makeanchor#2#3\@nil{%
  \caption@iftokens{#2}{%
    \caption@getlabel{#2}% copy \label inside the argument
    \begingroup
      \let\label\@gobble% deactivate \label for printing the caption
      \xcapitalisefmtwords{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }{%
    \caption@getlabel{#1}% copy \label inside the argument
    \begingroup
      \let\label\@gobble
      \xcapitalizefmtwords{#1}% deactivate \label for printing the caption
    \endgroup
  }%
  \caption@thelabel\caption@clrlabel % execute copied \label and clean the storage
}
\makeatother
\captionsetup{textformat=casing}

\begin{document} 
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{this is my figure heading for first figure} % does capitalize
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \hline
            Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
            Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\label{tab:my_label} a simple table with three columns and three rows.} % does not capitalize
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}



With the upcoming (2025-06-01) LaTeX release, you'll be able to use
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{casing}{\MakeTitlecase[words = all]{#1}}

You can test this right now if you use the dev version of LaTeX, but this is pre-release code so there may be issues.

Fantastic! Will there be a way to add words that will never be capitalized? Or is there a list of common english words that will not be capitalized by default? (a an in the on and etc.)

@SamuelSaari That's a feature request we've logged for the underlying expl3 code - probably some time in the spring and in time for the 2025-06-01 release (I know what to do, it's just a question of time to do it)

https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1614

Since you are using R to produce the tables, use  R  to capitalize the captions. The labels are placed automatically after that in a good place, so they are not a problem.
Note: A good place for a table/figure label is any position inside the caption and even after it. What is wrong is placing it before the caption, because then will take the counter of the former float.
Note that with the new Quarto format, you can even set captions and labels from the R cell options, simplifying the kable formula and allowing cross-references in markdown syntax (compare the reference methods of the two tables).

mwe.qmd:
---
keep-tex: true
papersize: a6
execute:
  echo: false
---

```{r}
#| label: function
library(knitr) 

## https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364905/2803235

simpleCap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), 
  substring(s, 2), sep="", collapse=" ")}
```

Link to @tbl-cars.

Link to Table \ref{tab:cap2}

```{r}

kable(head(mtcars[1:2],3),"latex", booktabs=T, 
  caption=simpleCap("i do not like capitalize words myself"),
  label="cap2"
  )

```


```{r}
#| label: tbl-cars
#| tbl-cap: !expr simpleCap("this table is shorter but wider")

kable(head(mtcars[1:4],2),"latex",booktabs=T)

```

After compilation, you can open mwe.tex to check the generated latex code.

Related to Fran's answer, there are built-in methods in R to provide sentence case. One is tools::toTitleCase, which uses a stop word list to capitalize only meaningful words. Example:
library(knitr)
mycaption <- "a simple table with three columns and three rows."
kable(head(cars), format='latex', caption=tools::toTitleCase(mycaption), label="mylabel", booktabs=TRUE)

Result:
\caption{\label{tab:mylabel}a Simple Table with Three Columns and Three Rows.}

The disadvantage is that this doesn't capitalize the first word if it is a stop word, like in the example above a simple table will become a Simple Table. You can write a wrapper function that does the capitalization separately for the first word and let tools::toTitleCase do the rest.
library(knitr)
library(stringr)

tc_first <- function(sentence){
   words <- strsplit(sentence, " ")[[1]]
   firstcap <- paste0(toupper(str_sub(words[1],1,1)), str_sub(words[1],2))
   return(paste(firstcap, tools::toTitleCase(paste(words[-1], collapse=" ")), collapse=" "))
}

kable(head(cars), format='latex', caption=tc_first(mycaption), label="mylabel", booktabs=TRUE)

This function splits the sentence into words, then splits the first word into the first letter and the rest, capitalizes the first letter, puts the first word back together, runs tools::toTitleCase on the remaining words, and combines it with the first word that was already capitalized.
Result:
\caption{\label{tab:mylabel}A Simple Table with Three Columns and Three Rows.}

Alternatively you can use str_to_title from the stringr library, which capitalizes all words:
library(knitr)
library(stringr)

kable(head(cars), format='latex', caption=str_to_title(mycaption), label="mylabel", booktabs=TRUE)

Result:
\caption{\label{tab:mylabel}A Simple Table With Three Columns And Three Rows.}

